# getting the other values from other td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay i have a HTML TABLE , with 4 TDs in a TR(tow) as shown in the code below:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="1">Lemon</td>
      <td class="2">Orange</td>
      <td class="3">Tea</td>
      <td class="4"><a href=#" class="get">Get</a></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class="1">Apple</td>
      <td class="2">Tomato</td>
      <td class="3">Pineapple</td>
      <td class="4"><a href="#" class="get">Get</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can i use jQuery to make , when a#GET is clicked , it will go get the class 1 , 2 , 3 values which is in the same table row as it.

For example , i click on the a#get in the first row , i will get Lemon , orange , tea as the results.

I use the jQuery code below but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a#get').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val1 = $(this).parent().find('td.1').html();
    var val2 = $(this).parent().find('td.2').html();
    var val3 =  $(this).parent().find('td.3').html();
    alert(val1 + val2 + val3);
 });
});
```

Any ideas on how can i do this or what i'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: You have used an ID twice. An ID must be unique, otherwise it is not really an ID anymore.

Comment: Your quotes don't match on the `href` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `.find()` inside the `td` element, while you actually need to call it in `tr`, which is one level higher.

Replace `$(this).parent().find(...)` with `$(this).parent().parent().find(...)`.

(And you should make your IDs unique, as pimvdb suggested.)

Answer (score 1):

### [See Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ejaguj)

You should use unique `id`, here is modfifed code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a.get').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.1').html();
    var val2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.2').html();
    var val3 =  $(this).closest('tr').find('td.3').html();
    alert(val1 + val2 + val3);
 });
});
```

Using `parent` you were getting back to `td` because link is inside that, you needed to get back to `tr` which is done through `closest('tr')`. Also html has been modified for link element to have unique id.

```
<a href=#" class="get">Get</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no point adding a class to the cells, if they're just numerical - you can use `eq()` for that.

[Here's how I'd do it:](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/bTMGj/)

```
$('#table-id tr').each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).find('td');
    $(this).find('a.get').click(function() {
        alert(tds.eq(0).html() + tds.eq(1).html() + tds.eq(2).html());
        return false;
    });
});
```